# Gmail searching, labeling, and deleting are broken. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to tidy up my Gmail account because I'm nearing my 15GB free limit, but Gmail is thwarting me.

For instance, if I tell Gmail to delete the 10,000 junk emails that I got from Aperture Laboratories, Gmail will keep erroring out in the middle of deleting them, and I have to ask Gmail to do the deletion over and over again until it finally succeeds. (Then I get to have similar fun emptying the Trash.)

This is painful enough, but it gets ***much*** worse. I.e., I can't safely delete emails using simple queries.

E.g., I should be able to search for messages using this syntax:

```
from:aplabs.co -label:receipts
```

With this query, I should get a list of all the "conversations" from Aperature Laboratories that I haven't labeled with "receipts". I want this so that I can delete all the junk from Aperature Laboratories without deleting my receipts from them.

Once I have such a list of such conversations, I should be able to delete them all without losing my receipts. But does this query work? ***Nooooooooo!***

I'll end up gettings conversations in the results that ***do*** have the label "receipts". Meaning that I can't safely delete all of the conversations that match the query.

The Internet says that the reason that the query I included above doesn't work is because Gmail lies and indicates that labels apply to conversations when really they are only attached to individual messages. So if ***any*** message in a conversation doesn't have the label "receipts", the entire conversation will be displayed as not having the label, even though Gmail displays the conversation as indeed having the label. Confusing!

It has been suggested to me that I can solve this problem by turning off "Conversation View" and working at the level of the individual messages. But this doesn't work, since my receipts, as individual messages, are not necessarily labeled as being receipts, so I'll end up deleting many of my receipts.

I.e., I typically operate in Conversation mode, so when I apply the "receipts" label to a conversation, who knows what Gmail is doing? But not all messages in the conversation end up with the "receipts" label. Including, as is often the case, the actual receipt!

It has also been suggested to me that I can search for all conversations that have the label "receipts" and apply a new label "receipts1" to this search result. "receipts1" will then supposedly get applied to ***all*** of the individual messages.

Perhaps this would work if I could do it, but I have literally about 10,000 conversations that are labeled as "receipts" (I've been using Gmail for a ***long*** time), and if I try to do this, Gmail will report that it has applied the label "receipts1" to all of the conversations matching the search, but it will ***not*** have. (The exact message I will see on the Gmail screen is, 'All conversations added to "receipts1"'.)

But the above claim will ***not*** be true. Gmail will have applied the label to the first thousand or two conversations and then silently failed to apply "receipts1" to the rest of the conversations.

***Q. Is there any solution to this, or am I fsck'ed?***

E.g., is there software out there somewhere that can use the Gmail API to apply a label to ***all*** of the messages that match a conversation search? And do so without timing out or silently failing in the middle?

Or is there an alternative third-party Gmail client that puts more effort into correct behavior?

Etc.

I never imagined that Gmail would put me in such a pickle where I am unable to delete vast amounts of garbage in order to preserve a tiny important fraction of my messages that I carefully labeled for this particular purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I've searched for large attachments, but that's not the problem. The problem is that I literally do have hundreds of thousands of emails and I need to delete them by the tens of thousands.

The first thing I tried was to download Wundermail, but it turns out that it's Windows-only, and I'm Mac-only.

Comment: @mashuptwice Thanks, I'm quite familiar with Thunderbird. Its notion of folders doesn't map well onto Gmail's notion of labels. Unless you only ever applied a single label to a message, but I often apply a number of labels. So one thing I could possibly do is just abandon this Gmail account. Leave it there as an archive, and switch to Thunderbird backed by a different Gmail account, or what have you, for future use. But ideally, I'd like to be able to rescue this Gmail account.

Comment: @mashuptwice Another alternative is just to never delete anything. I can get 100GB for $2/month. That should last me for a while. And 2TB for $10/month. I'd never run out of that. It's the negative searches and deletions that really kill you with Gmail. I didn't notice this problem for years because I never really tried to clean up the mess it's become until now.

Comment: @barlop I dug up my old MacBook which I have running Windows on, so that I could try out Wundermail, but I guess Wundermail is either designed for faster computers, or for fewer conversations assigned to a label. It's incredibly slow just to display a large "folder" on my computer. And by incredibly slow, I mean that it's been like an hour and it's still thinking. I guess it's trying to load up all 8,000 conversations assinged to the label, rather than just showing me the first 100?

Comment: What error message is being shown when the delete fails to complete?

Comment: @BlindSpots No error message, IIRC. It just eventually stops without having deleted everything. This is definitely the case if I try to apply a label to the results from a large search result set. It will say that it has completed labeling everything, but it hasn't. I CAN eventually delete everything or label everything via a lot of persistence. And yes, I click on "Select all conversations that match this search". It will usually end up doing 1,000 or 2,000 messages at a time, but sometimes there are tens of thousands of messages that match the search.